# Как написать клиентскую фильтрацию в angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

Пишу обучающий проект на Angular. Приложение отображает посты из фейк-апи https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/. Требуется реализовать фильтрацию по колонкам. Создала форму с помощью "new FormGroup({})" и контролы тоже, затем подписалась на изменение событий значения, где создала объект params и постаралась сделать фильтрацию хотя бы для title, но она не работает как нужно. Как можно это исправить? Как правильно написать фильтрацию на стороне клиента для каждого столбца?

Посмотреть проект можно тут: [проект](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-breeze-48fwm?file=/src/app/posts/posts.component.ts)

posts.component.ts:

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  Output,
  SimpleChanges,
  EventEmitter
} from "@angular/core";
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";
import { Post, PostService } from "../post.service";
import { User, UserService } from "../user.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-posts",
  templateUrl: "./posts.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./posts.component.css"]
})
export class PostsComponent implements OnInit {
  page: any = 1;

  posts: Post[] = [];
  users: User[] = [];

  columns: any = [
    { title: "User id", filterKey: "userIdType", value: "usd" },
    { title: "User name", filterKey: "user", value: "us" },
    { title: "Title", filterKey: "titleArticle", value: "tart" }
  ];

  @Output() filterChange = new EventEmitter();
  form!: FormGroup;

  public totalItems: number = 100;
  public itemsPerPage: number = 10;

  error = "";

  constructor(
    private postService: PostService,
    private userService: UserService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchPosts();
    this.fetchUsers();

    this.form = new FormGroup({});

    for (let column of this.columns) {
      this.form.addControl(column.filterKey, new FormControl(""));
    }

    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((values) => {
      const params: any = {};

      for (let key in values) {
        if (values[key]) {
          params[key] = values[key];
          console.log("params", params);

          this.posts = this.posts.filter(post => {
            return post.title.toUpperCase().includes(params[key].toUpperCase())
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log("ngOnChanges");
  }

  onChangePage(event: any) {
    this.page = event;
    this.fetchPosts();
  }

  fetchPosts() {
    this.postService.fetchPosts(this.page, this.itemsPerPage).subscribe(
      (posts) => {
        this.posts = posts;
      },
      (error) => {
        this.error = error.message;
      }
    );
  }

  fetchUsers() {
    this.userService.fetchUsers().subscribe((users) => {
      this.users = users;
    });
  }
}
```

posts.component.html:

```
<table (filterChange)="filterChanged($event)">
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width: 10%;" />
    <col style="width: 15%;" />
    <col style="width: 75%;" />
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let column of columns">{{ column.title }}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr [formGroup]="form">
      <th *ngFor="let column of columns">
        <ng-container *ngIf="column.filterKey">
          <input type="text" [formControlName]="column.filterKey" />
        </ng-container>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of posts">
      <td>{{ item.userId }}</td>
      <td>
        <div *ngFor="let user of users">
          {{ item.userId === user.id ? user.username : '' }}
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a [routerLink]="['/posts', item.id]">{{ item.title | titlecase }}</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужно удалять данные массива posts (т.к. в этом случае нужно будет заново получать весь массив при каждом изменении данных для фильтации), можно добавить какой-то флаг и по нему скрывать-показывать данные:

```
fetchPosts() {
  this.postService.fetchPosts(this.page, this.itemsPerPage).subscribe(
    (posts) => {
      this.posts = posts;
      // - добавляем всем постам параметр show: true
      // чтобы изначально вы видели их все
      this.posts.map((post: unknown) => {
        post.show =  true
        return post
      });
    },
    (error) => {
      this.error = error.message;
    }
  );
}
```

Используем данный параметр в html:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of posts">
  <tr *ngIf="item.show">
    <td>{{ item.userId }}</td>
    <td>
      <div *ngFor="let user of users">
        {{ item.userId === user.id ? user.username : '' }}
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a [routerLink]="['/posts', item.id]">{{ item.title | titlecase }}</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Осталось для самой фильрации добавить изменения атрибута для отображения фильтрованых данных:

```
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((values) => {
  const params: any = {};
  console.log(values);
  for (let key in values) {
    if (values[key]) {
      params[key] = values[key];
      console.log("params", params);

      // проходимся по массиву с постами и меняем значение show
      this.posts.map((post: unknown) => {
        post.show = post.title.toUpperCase().includes(params[key].toUpperCase())
        return post
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Но не стоит забывать, поскольку это "локальная" фильтрация то и данные мы фильтруем в пределах текущей страницы. Чтобы фильтрация работала корректно - делать нужно, так называемую, server-side фильтрацию (в Вашем случае, у данного ресурса: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/guide/ - заголовок Filtering resources)

***UPD.*** Осталась небольшая проблема: когда значение фильтра удаляется - остаётся последний фильтр. Избежать этого достаточно просто:
Когда срабатывает valueChanges для формы, давайте добавим проверку - пустые фильтры или же нет:

```
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((values) => {
  const params: any = {};
  console.log(values);
  // str будет содержать значения всех input эл-тов
  // или пустую строку, если они пустые, соответственно
  const str = Object.values(values).reduce((a:string,i:string)=>a+i);
  // если строка не пустая - фильтруем данные
  if (str) {
    for (let key in values) {
      if (values[key]) {
        params[key] = values[key];
        console.log("params", params);

        this.posts.map((post: unknown) => {
          post.show = post.title.toUpperCase().includes(params[key].toUpperCase())
          return post
        });
      }
    }
  // если строка пустая - опять делаем все данные видимыми
  } else {
    this.posts.map((post: unknown) => {
      post.show =  true
      return post
    });
  }
});
```

Вот и всё, теперь "локальный" фильтр работает как надо.
Так же, во избежания дублирования кода (DRY принцип), можно повторяющиеся код, как этот:

```
this.posts.map((post: unknown) => {
  post.show =  true
  return post
});
```

вынести в отдельную функцию и вызывать её где угодно.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! фильтрацию для title получилось сделать!